# How to display a website I don't own in "Offered by" field (Chrome Web Store)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to display a link to my deviant art group or link to my extension from Chrome Web Store in "Offered by" field of my theme, like in this theme: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%D1%8D%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F/ppbaibkigenhdcommebegmmmpoolmpip

The developer dashboard asks me to verify my website with Google Webmaster Tools, but obviously I don't own these websites. Is there other way?

Answer (score 2):

I think that is the only way to do it. You need to set up this in your Developer Dashboard as "Official Url".

And like you said, your site must be registered using Google Webmaster Tools.